# Tail command not tailing the newly created files under a directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, tail

I am trying to tail all the log files present under a directory and it's sub-directories recursively using below command

```
shopt -s globstar
tail -f -n +2 /app/mylogs/**/* | awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a":"$0}'
```

and the output is below:

```
/app/mylogs/myapplog10062020.log:Hi this is first line
/app/mylogs/myapplog10062020.log:Hi this is second line
```

which is fine, but problem is when I add a new log file under `/app/mylogs/`,directory after I fire  above `tail` command. `tail` will not take that new file into consideration.
Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: You need to pass new file as argument to tail command. Check `inotifywait` utility

Answer (score 2):

When you start your the `tail` process, you pass to it a (fixed) list of the files which tail is suppoed to follow, as you can see from the *tail* man page. This is different to, say, 'find', where you can in its options pass a file name pattern. After the process has been started, `tail` has no way of knowing that you suddenly want it to follow another file too.

If you want to have a feature like this, you would have to program your own version of `tail`, which gets passed for instance a directory to scan, and either periodically checks the directory content for change, or using a service such as [*inotify*](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to be informed by directory changes.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428. I shall try that